# JavaFx: Space between left, center and right in BorderPane

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have a `BorderPane` with `Pane`s for left, right and center elements and `HBox` for top element. A size of my scene is `700` for width and `600` for height. For the left `Pane` I `setMaxWidth` at `(700 - 400)/2 = 150`, the same goes for the right `Pane`, while the center `Pane` has max width equal to `400`.

```
public class Main extends Application implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {
    private static BorderPane gamePane;
    private static Pane cellsPane;
    private static HBox buttonsPane;
    private static Pane statsPane;
    private static Pane setupsPane;

    Label cellsCountLabel;    

    static int  gameWidth= 700;
    static int gameHeight=600;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");

        gamePane = new BorderPane();

        buttonsPane = new HBox(5);
        statsPane = new Pane();
        cellsPane = makeGrid(20);
        setupsPane = new Pane();

        cellsPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color:  #ffffff; -fx-border-color: black");
        buttonsPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color:  #f2f2f2; -fx-border-color: black");
        statsPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color:  #f2f2f2; -fx-border-color: black");
        setupsPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color:  #f2f2f2; -fx-border-color: black");

        cellsPane.setMaxWidth(400);
        statsPane.setMaxWidth((gameWidth-400)/2);
        setupsPane.setMaxWidth((gameWidth-400)/2);

        createCellButton = new Button();
        deleteCellsButton = new Button();

        createCellButton.setText("Create a cell");
        deleteCellsButton.setText("Delete cells");

        ...

        buttonsPane.setSpacing(10);
        buttonsPane.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        buttonsPane.getChildren().add(createCellButton);
        buttonsPane.getChildren().add(deleteCellsButton);

        gamePane.setTop(buttonsPane);
        gamePane.setCenter(cellsPane);

        ...

        cellsCountLabel = new Label("Cells Count: " + (cellId + 1));
        statsPane.getChildren().add(cellsCountLabel);
        gamePane.setLeft(statsPane);

        setupsPane.getChildren().add(new Label("Setups Panel"));
        gamePane.setRight(setupsPane);

        gamePane.setMargin(statsPane, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
        gamePane.setMargin(cellsPane, new Insets(0,0,0,0));
        gamePane.setMargin(setupsPane, new Insets(0,0,0,0));

        Scene scene = new Scene(gamePane, gameWidth, gameHeight);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        ...

        primaryStage.show();
}
...
}
```

However, there exists space between left, center and right `Pane`s. The space gets smaller as the content in those `Pane`s get larger, however, when it gets too large it messes with the center `Pane`.

[image]

[image]

Each `Pane` has borders to see its limits more clearly. I want the `Pane`s to take up exactly `150`, `400` and `150` space, without empty spaces inbetween and also without invading center's `Pane` border.

I tried using `gamePane.setMargin(..., new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));` but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: I am not very experienced with javafx at all however can you not use `setPreferredWidth` to always take up the width you specify, as opposed to `setMaxWidth` which allocates a certain amount of space?

Comment: @nbokmans It worked, thank you! Though now it cuts the label's content if it's too long for 150 width... `cellsCountLabel.setWrapText(true)` doesn't work.